# How best can I find the key of a specific value in a nested situation?

Tags: lua, nested, lua-table

In a Lua table, how best can I find the key of a specific value
in a nested situation (following table, originating from JSON)?

```
[{"Code": "AF", "Name": "Afghanistan"},
{"Code": "AL", "Name": "Albania"},
...
]
```

For example, I can use table[2]["Name"] to fetch "Albania", but how can I get [2], only by specifying "Albania"?

Comment: Why don't t use dictionary in json? It will turn into fast lua table!

Comment: How do you do that? Do you have a code example with the data above? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the array and test each value:

```
for i,v in ipairs(table) do
    if v.Name == "Albania" then
        return v.Code
    end
end
```

You can also put the values as key-pair in a new table once so you can query directly:

```
local codeFromName={}
for i,v in ipairs(table) do
    codeFromName[v.Name]=v.Code
end
```

Comment: Ok thanks! But I don't need v.Code (i.e. "AL"). I need interger key (i.e. 2).

Comment: @user7665853 replace `v.Code` with `i` then

Comment: Aha so easy it is. It is Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,v in ipairs(table) do
    if string.match(v.Name, countryName) then
        print(i)
    end
end
```

srting.match is used instead of v.Name == "Albania", as Ive realised there is a possibility in other cases where country names are present, but may not be exactly the same.